# How can I get the response results from jQuery3310.....: In my Network tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, response

How can I get the response results from `jQuery33106831683794919328_1519575172879`, which is seen my Network tab in Chrome. See the Screenshot below

Additionally based on this data a table is made. The ajax call is made from external script, which isn't within my react-app. The script is declared in `index.html` and called in the components with `window.` [image: JSON Data Response]

Comment: jQuery3310 ... a question from the future ..?

Comment: Look the picture it's screenshot under `Inspect mode` in Chrome.  Right side under `Response`. It is even marked with red. There is `jQuery33106831683794919328_1519575172879` which returns json data. I want to find out how can I get the results it returns and handle them in my react component.

Comment: You know, you can actually copy and paste from that Response tab into the question so that we don't have to try and see your picture... You'll also want to provide a way for others to reproduce this. See [mcve].